# Does a Twilio Messaging Service prevent "snowshoe messaging" when sending a bulk text?

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

I've been reading up on the Twilio documentation regarding text queue limits for long code numbers (14,400 segments max for 1 MPS). The docs suggest adding more numbers to a Messaging Service to load balance many requests. However, I also read in the docs that texts can be filtered by carriers if their systems detect "snowshoe" messaging - meaning that the same text is being sent from multiple numbers.

So if I have 2 US local numbers in my Messaging Service, will Twilio help prevent snowshoe-ing somehow since it suggests adding more numbers to load balance? I can't seem to find a definitive answer.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

While adding numbers to a messaging service can increase your throughput it is not recommended when sending the same message out to numbers in the US and Canada. If you are looking for higher throughput it is better to consider [toll-free numbers or short codes](https://www.twilio.com/docs/messaging/guides/best-practices-at-scale#use-a-short-code-or-toll-free-number-for-higher-throughput). You can read more about [choosing toll-free or short code numbers](https://www.twilio.com/learn/messaging/when-to-use-shortcode-vs-toll-free-sms) here. For even more certainty sending mass messages, you should investigate whether registering for A2P 10DLC could work for you and bring you higher throughput and better deliverability instead.